# Get multiple Sums for a vector with only 2 factor levels

Tags: r, vector

I have a very large Vector of the following form:

`T_Nights <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0[... and so on])`

This vector is kind of a flag for each 10 minutes of two years: "1" = night and "0" = day. This means a length of 105264!

Since the day- and nighttime per 24h differs from day to day over the year I need to get multiple Sums of "1" to get informations on how long my nights are.

Is there any possible way, to get sums of this vector for all my "1"-values, but still seperated from the next pack of contiguous "1"-values.
This way I could get a value for each night of the year telling me, how long it is in minutes (if multiplied by 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, you could use the `rle` function which computes the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector.

```
## Example data
T_Nights = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)

r = rle(T_Nights)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:6] 11 12 9 5 4 1
  values : num [1:6] 0 1 0 1 0 1

r$lengths[r$values==1]
[1] 12  5  1
```